# UITableView backgroundView gestures on iOS 7?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller subclass. I'm trying to connect a gesture recognizer to trap taps below the rows.

To do this, I have an empty row at the bottom, so the user can always scroll so there's an empty cell on the screen. I can trap taps on this row easily.

But Reminders on iOS 7 supports tapping even under that; if there's space for three more rows on the table, any of those three can be tapped not just the first one.

For example, you can tap in the red area:

[image]

To do this on iOS 6, I added a background view to the table and hooked a gesture recognizer to it:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:_tapOutsideGesture];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

This works when on 6.1, but not 7.0. What am I missing?

I'm building with Xcode 5.0 and the 7.0 SDK, with `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and check in which view you are, and if you are in table cell then return `NO`.

Off course there are some issues with iOS7. 
If you would like to check if you are in `UITableViewCell` you have to call `view.superview.superview` in iOS7 and in iOS6 it was `view.superview`.

More info about iOS7:
[How to get UITableView from UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711645/how-to-get-uitableview-from-uitableviewcell/18408043#18408043) https://devforums.apple.com/message/865550#865550

Answer (score 2):

Add a gesture recognizer in your table view

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

and check if the tap was over some cell.

```
#pragma mark – UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

   return ![self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[touch locationInView:self.tableView]];
}
```