# iOS Keyboard, VoiceOver and accessibilityViewIsModal

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to make a inputAccessoryView AND the keyboard modal for VoiceOver users so they don't get lost.  Setting:

```
view.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;
textField.inputAccessoryView = view;
```

Makes the view modal with keyboard visible but unusable - it is outside of the modal view.

Next I tried this after the keyboard has appeared:

```
textField.inputAccessoryView.superview.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;
```

Which seems a bit out of bounds but almost worked - but the keys physical after B (N, M space, etc) were not navigable.

Next up was this:

```
textField.inputAccessoryView.superview.superview.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;
```

and everything works just fine.  That view, BTW logs as follows:

```
<UITextEffectsWindow: 0x17170290; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17170710>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x17170430>>
```

My question is this:  I this a stupid thing to do?  Seems like it.  Is it legal?  UITextEffectsWindow is private, but I'm not actually using it, just taking advantage of the fact that it's a view.

Any input or ways to work around the problem would help.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? accessibilityViewIsModal will only block sibling views from getting focus. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not illegal, but it is safe to assume it will stop working in future versions of iOS.

For example, in iOS 6, a developer could get from a cell to its tableview by calling `self.superview`.  In iOS 7, there is now a private-classed view in between.

You may want to take a more dynamic approach, like traversing up the view hierarchy until you find a view with the correct frame, or with all of the views you need as its subviews.  A similar [approach for the UITableViewCell problem can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18780157/1445366).