# How to delete UITableViewCell from within same cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` with custom table view cell.

That cell has a custom delete button. Button action is within the cell class.

I can't reload the table from cell class after deleted row from db. If I try to get table view from `cell.superview` or `cell.superview.superview`, the app crashes.

This is cell implementation

```
@implementation pixSavedTableViewCell

- (IBAction)deleteBusiness:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"DELETING BUSINESS cell");
    self.hidden=YES;
    pixDBManager *dbConnection = [[pixDBManager alloc]init];
    dbConnection.businessName = self.nameLable.text;
    [dbConnection deleteBusiness];
    //[(UITableView *)self.superview.superview reloadData];
}
@end
```

This will delete data from

```
-(void)deleteBusiness
{
    NSLog(@"DELETING BUSINESS");
    char *error;
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &businessDB)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *deleteStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM SAVEDBUSINESS      WHERE 'NAME'='%@'",_businessName];
        const char *delete_stmt = [deleteStatement UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"%s",delete_stmt);
        if (sqlite3_exec(businessDB, delete_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Business Deleted");

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Cant Delete Data");
        }
        sqlite3_close(businessDB);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Cant Open Data Base");
    }
}
```

This is my view controller implementation

```
@implementation pixSavedViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *businessArray;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pixDBManager *dbConnection = [[pixDBManager alloc]init];
    businessArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [dbConnection createOrOpenDB];
    businessArray = [dbConnection getSavedBusiness];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return businessArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *customcellidentifier = @"CustomCell3";

    pixSavedTableViewCell *cell = (pixSavedTableViewCell *)[tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customcellidentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Savedcell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    pixBusinessDetails *details = [[pixBusinessDetails alloc]init];
    details = [businessArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLable.text = details.name;
    cell.addressLable.text = details.address;
    cell.descriptionLable.text = details.description;
    cell.scoreLable.text = details.score;
    cell.votesLable.text = details.votes;
    NSLog(@"Business Detail %@\n %@\n %@\n %@\n %@\n %@\n",details.name, details.address,details.description,details.score,details.votes,details.imageId);

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
    return 130;
}
```

Comment: I think your issue is the way you're trying to get the superview. You cannot make the assumption that the cells superview is the tableview. Instead you need to traverse the hierarchy until its found. See this answer for help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711645/how-to-get-uitableview-from-uitableviewcell

Comment: If you have a question, I would ask that instead of just posting code and telling us what is wrong with it.

Comment: What you're trying to do is like killing yourself and pretending to clean up the mess after you're already dead  xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than deleting the data from within the `UITableViewCell`, you should instead call a method in your `UIViewController` which will delete the data and then reload the table.

On way to do this is to create a protocol for your UIViewController to conform to:

```
@protocol pixSavedTableViewCellDelegate
- (void)deleteBuisness:(NSString *) businessName
@end

@interface pixSavedTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<pixSavedTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Then in you `UITableViewCell` you change your delete method to:

```
- (IBAction)deleteBusiness:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate deleteBuisness:self.nameLabel.text];
}
```

In your `UIViewController` you then implement the protocol:

```
@interface pixSavedViewController <pixSavedTableViewCellDelegate>
@end

@implementation pixSavedViewController
#pragma mark - pixSavedTableViewCellDelegate
- (void)deleteBuisness:(NSString *) businessName
{
    pixDBManager *dbConnection = [[pixDBManager alloc]init];
    dbConnection.businessName = businessName;
    [dbConnection deleteBusiness];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You'll also need to set the delegate when creating the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    //All your current code
    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Nice Approach. Good one

Comment: - (IBAction)deleteBusiness:(id)sender {
    
    NSLog(@"Deleting");
    [self.delegate deleteBuisness:self.nameLable.text];
}
@end
This function not executing......

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the method and make sure self.delegate is not nil. I presume you also made the all changes to your UIViewController?

Comment: Sorry karl i confused, It executed upto [dbConnection deleteBusiness];
but didnt worked [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Well is self.tableView the same name as your `UITableView` property? Is an error thrown?

Comment: Yes
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Comment: Hey karl that is my mistake,Your answer is correct i forgot to reallocate the datasourse array. now i added  businessArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; businessArray = [dbConnection getSavedBusiness];. Now its worked perfectly what how i expect. Thanx very very thanx :). This is my first question in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the delegate pattern is for, in my opinion:

Make your `UITableViewController` a delegate of your custom cell.

```
MyCustomCell *cell = ....
cell.deleteDelegate = self

//in your UITableViewController
- (void)willDeleteCustomCell:(MyCustomCell*)cell
{

}

//on your cell
- (IBAction)deleteBusiness:(id)sender
{
     [self.deleteDelegate willDeleteCustomCell:self];

     //rest of your delete code
}
```

Comment: I did this but 
- (IBAction)deleteBusiness:(id)sender
this function not executing...

Comment: I was under the assumption that this method was already connected correctly in your project. What did you do to make it stop working?

Comment: yes this method connected correctly... i added NSLog to that method. And i ran the app.it didnt executed NSlog. when i remove [self.deleteDelegate willDeleteCustomCell:self] method, it executed NSlog..

Comment: I don't understand. If you add an `NSLog` after the line `[self.deleteDelegate willDeleteCustomCell:self]` and the `NSLog` doesn't get executed, then I assume your app must crash? The simple presence of a line inside a method will not prevent that method from getting executed.

Comment: Thats exactly happened...i added NSLog before    [self.deleteDelegate willDeleteCustomCell:self] and 
The simple presence of a line inside a method did prevent that method from getting executed

Comment: I can't imagine any scenario where that is logical.

Comment: No I cannot. You should post your current relevant code which is your cell and your view controller.

Comment: Adam this answer also correct but i cant accept two answer in a question. thanx very much..