# How to access UITableView from within UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have TableView with cells and I have button on each cell. I want to add some functionality - when user presses button in cell some request is made to server and cell disappears from TableView.

How i can perform this? I know method to delete cell from tableView but to use it i need to get access to tableView from it's cell.

Comment: Are you asking how to access `UITableView` from within `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Yes, that is the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get UITableView from UITableViewCell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711645/how-to-get-uitableview-from-uitableviewcell)

Comment: no: 1) it is not in Swift, 2) i don't understand how to do it in Obj-c

Comment: See this answer in there http://stackoverflow.com/a/18780157/1891327

Comment: sorry, i do not understand Obj-C - i need code for button  action inside cell

Comment: iosDev82, why downvote?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87712/discussion-between-iosdev82-and-moonvader).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way could be to add a callback closure to a custom cell and execute it upon cell selection. your view controller would hook this callback up in `tableView(_,cellForIndexPath:)` or `tableView(_, cellWillAppear:)`

---

```
import UIKit

class SelectionCallbackTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var selectionCallback: (() -> Void)?
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.selectionCallback?()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.button)
    }
}
```

---

register the cell for the tableview. I did it in the storyboard.

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var array = [1,1]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for x in stride(from: 2, through: 30, by: 1){
            let i = array[x-2]
            let j = array[x-1]
            array.append(i+j)
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectionCallbackTableViewCell
        cell.selectionCallback = {
            println("\(self.array[indexPath.row]) at \(indexPath.row) on \(tableView) selected")
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(self.array[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

}
```

---

Now implement the callback closure as needed

```
cell.selectionCallback = {
    println("\(self.array[indexPath.row]) at \(indexPath.row) on \(tableView) selected")
}
```

will result in logs like

```
832040 at 29 on <UITableView: 0x7fe290844200; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe2907878e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe290711e60>; contentOffset: {0, 697}; contentSize: {375, 1364}> selected
```

all possible helpful information are present:

- indexPath
- datasource object
- table view
- cell

if you want delete the cell after successfully informing your server, for a simple solution do:

```
cell.selectionCallback = {
    println("\(self.array[indexPath.row]) at \(indexPath.row) on \(tableView) selected")

    self.apiManager.deleteObject(obj, success: { response in
        self.array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }, failure:{ error in 
        // handle error
    })

}
```

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:**</sub>
<sub>Personally I don't recommend to implement datasources as UIViewController. It violates the SOLID principles.</sub>  
<sub>Instead datasources should reside in their own classes.</sub>  
<sub>For my own Projects I use an architecture I call ["OFAPopulator"](http://vikingosegundo.github.io/ofapopulator/), that allows me to create independent datasources for each section of a table or collection view.</sub>  
<sub>I chose to implement it inside the view controller here for brevity.</sub>

---

I missed the button part. edited.

---

Example code: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/CellSelectionCallback