# Is it possible to figure out what part of the cell is visible from inside the cell subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview

In my cell subclass the user can slide the cell for actions, just like in Mail.app. However, the cells can be much larger than Mail.app, sometimes up to 1,000pt which means it requires the table to be scrolled to read fully.

This means that the normal strategy of simply centering the actions vertically in the cell will not work, as the vertical center could very well not be visible. So I want to display it in the vertical center of the *visible area*.

Is this possible to do within the `UITableViewCell` subclass where the sliding action is occurring? Figuring out where the vertical center of the visible area even is?

Comment: Intersect the cell's frame with the table view's bounds.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it bad MVC practice or bad on memory to keep a reference/delegate of the table view in each cell?

Comment: The cell already has a reference to the table view - it is the cell's `superview`.

Comment: @rmaddy As shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18408043/998117) that's not the case unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I misspoke a bit. You need to walk up the superview chain until you get to the table view.